# Angular-UI Datepicker: `format-day-header` format with with 2 letters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to display angular ui datepicker with day header (Format of day in week header) with 2 letters
the defualt in 3 letters and is defined by attr format-day-header="EEE"
where can i find the option for 2 letters?
(Ive tried 'EE' it just writes EE in the header).

the plunker is [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q55ZnKgcTMin07BUrnIz?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $scope.status.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

  $scope.status = {
    opened: false
  };

  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
  $scope.events =
    [
      {
        date: tomorrow,
        status: 'full'
      },
      {
        date: afterTomorrow,
        status: 'partially'
      }
    ];

  $scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i=0;i<$scope.events.length;i++){
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

    <h4>Inline</h4>
    <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
      <datepicker ng-model="dt" format-day-header="EEE" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>
    </div>

    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2020-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2020-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Format:</label> <select class="form-control" ng-model="format" ng-options="f for f in formats"><option></option></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="dt = '2009-08-24'">2009-08-24</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleMin()" tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is how you can accept answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem, searched for `EEE` in **ui-bootstrap.js / ui-bootstrap-tpls.js** files, they are using `regex: $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.SHORTDAY.join('|')` for feeding the value for `EEE` attributes.

### Better Way

Update the `provider` `$locale`'s `SHORTDAY` using `$provide.decorator`

```
myApp.config(['$provide', Decorate]);
function Decorate($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$locale', function ($delegate) {
    var value = $delegate.DATETIME_FORMATS;

    value.SHORTDAY = [
        "Su",
        "Mo",
        "Tu",
        "We",
        "Th",
        "Fr",
        "Sa"
    ];

    return $delegate;
  });
};
```

Wrote this article [Customizing Angular-UI Bootstrap’ Directives](https://productblog.townscript.com/customizing-angular-ui-bootstrap-directives-c4461c12afa9#.8ju7xuqiz) for more customization you may want to do.

### Other Way

You have to **search** for `SHORTDAY` in `angular.js` which you're using and edit it according to your need.

Ex:

```
"SHORTDAY": [
  "Su",
  "Mo",
  "Tu",
  "We",
  "Th",
  "Fr",
  "Sa"
],
```

This should work :)

Also you can create a new association of `EE` (in ui-bootstrap or ui-bootstrap-tpls) and define it in Angular.js with value you want, haven't tried but should work.

Tell me if there's any better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The format for two letters would be

```
format-day-header="EEEEEE"
```

That should return Mo, Tu, and so on.